# asp.net 4.0 Custom 401.2 not Authorized custom page

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-401

I successfully implemented role based authorization in ASP.NET. When a person does not have the needed role he gets to see an error page for 401.2 not authorized. 
What I would like to accomplish now is to have a custom 401 page in my application and have it redirected there via settings in the web.config. I tried this:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm"><error statusCode="401" redirect="NoAccess.htm" /></customErrors>
```

But this does not get caught. Do I have to override it in IIS instead? I hope not as that would make getting things deployed harder

Comment: From where are you testing the setting? If you set mode to "RemoteOnly" you'll be redirected only if you try to access the site from a remote client.

Comment: I tried other options as well like "Off" , but for no help

Comment: [Check out your answer here ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9196564/726802)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be running into is that you have security set for the entire application. That is when a 401 occurs the redirect to NoAccess.htm fails because the user does not have access to that file either. Since you didn't post the whole file I cannot be sure, but that is my best guess.

Make sure that you have a <location path="/NoAccess.htm"><system.web><authorization><allow users="?" /></authorization<</system.web> in your web.config file.